# Microsoft fastCGI versus Zend fastCGI while using IIS and Zend Server on windows

Tags: iis, fastcgi, zend-server

In one scenario we are using " OS 2012 R2 + IIS 8.5 + Zend Server 8.5 " for our web application and in another scenario we are using same OS and IIS, but Zend Server version 7.5;

Is there a such a thing as using Microsoft fastCGI versus Zend fastCGI ?

Currently, I notice that our IIS fast CGI module is pointing to zend folder and php-cgi under zend folder.

Which is better to use ? Microsoft fastCGI OR Zend fastCGI ?

Right now, we are seeing a lot of performance problems and fast-cgi processes seem to be guzzling CPU to the levels upward of 70% many times.

Thanks for any helpful insights in advance.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/who-should-be-contacted-for-php-on-iis-issues-c80b90bd365 There is neither "Microsoft FastCGI" nor "Zend FastCGI". Make sure you ask a valid question and then answers would follow.

Comment: @LexLi  - please refer to this URL http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/content/iis_configuration_optimization.htm  , where the opening line of the article starts talking about    "When moving from Zend Core to Zend Server on IIS, Microsoft's FastCGI is used instead of the Zend's FastCGI. Therfore, the settings and configurations are in a different location. For more information per IIS version, see below.".   So please think twice before you call someone else's question valid or not.

Comment: And @LexLi - please find below an answer written directly by Zend support in another forum:   "Microsoft FastCGI is newer and is recommended with IIS for production. Most Windows developers are installing Zend Server with Apache, so it needs a CGI layer which is the Zend Enabler wrapper. The CPU comes from php.exe processes, and would probably be the same when running under a different Fast-CGI wrapper Apache module (as we changed to Apache mod-fcgi in later Windows versions, and also provide that option with Zend Server for Linux, for anyone who prefers Apache over NginX).
..to be contd...

Comment: You cannot just change to a different FastCGI under Apache on a Zend Server version which was fully tested in our lab and get support, however you can still do that on your own - please check with our support team by opening a case with your questions and concerns.
CPU report also requires a support case as it should contain logs to process offline and tests to perform - not under this non-SLA forums.
Hope this helps!"

Comment: "Microsoft's FastCGI" is exactly what I wrote in the blog post, while "Zend's FastCGI" is something Zend created for its own. Review your own words above please, and see how misleading they are compared to Zend's official documentation. Even if you pasted the text in your question, it would be much clearer for further discussions.